# Combine if else statement with two conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

I have one dataset which contain two columns "Code" and "Gross_i".  You can see data below:

```
# Data
TABLE<-data.frame(Code=as.integer(c("1","2","3","4","5")),
                  Gross_i=as.integer(c("10","20","30","40","50")
                  ))

TAX_RATE1<-0.20
TAX_RATE2<-0.25
```

My intention here is to multiply second column "Gross_i" with two different tax rates.So I need to multiply first three code "1","2" and "3" with TAX_RATE1 (20%) and observation "4" and "5" with TAX_RATE2 (25%). In order to do this I try this line of code (If else statment) but results are not good:

```
   pit_1=if_else(filter(Code %in% c("1","2","3")),Gross_i*TAX_RATE1,Gross_i*TAX_RATE2)
```

So can anybody help how to fix this line of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach can be useful with `dplyr` in the field:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
TABLE %>% mutate(Value=if_else(Code %in% c("1","2","3"),Gross_i*TAX_RATE1,Gross_i*TAX_RATE2))
```

Output:

```
  Code Gross_i Value
1    1      10   2.0
2    2      20   4.0
3    3      30   6.0
4    4      40  10.0
5    5      50  12.5
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have only two tax rates, you can do :

```
library(dplyr)

TABLE %>% mutate(pit_1 = Gross_i * c(TAX_RATE2, TAX_RATE1)[(Code %in% 1:3) + 1])

#  Code Gross_i pit_1
#1    1      10   2.0
#2    2      20   4.0
#3    3      30   6.0
#4    4      40  10.0
#5    5      50  12.5
```

If you lot of rates like this it would be easy to specify conditions within `case_when` :

```
TABLE %>%
  mutate(pit_1 = Gross_i * case_when(Code %in% 1:3 ~ TAX_RATE1,
                                     TRUE ~ TAX_RATE2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt at `if_else` translates easily to the following using `ifelse`

```
pit_1 <- ifelse(TABLE$Code %in% c("1", "2", "3"), 
                yes = TABLE$Gross_i * TAX_RATE1, 
                no = TABLE$Gross_i * TAX_RATE2)
```